# Firebase Functions multiple directories - Nuxt 3 / Nitro

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js, firebase-hosting, nuxtjs3

I'm experimenting with Nuxt 3 on Firebase hosting and have a basic build deployed successfully.  However, it has taken over the functions directory.

Is it possible to specify a second directory in firebase.json?  Thanks.

Here is the relevant portion of my working-for-nuxt firebase.json file.

```
"functions": {
    "source": ".output/server",
    "runtime": "nodejs14",
    "ignore": [
      "node_modules",
      ".git",
      "firebase-debug.log",
      "firebase-debug.*.log"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Can you explain " it has taken over the functions directory." and how is that an issue?

Comment: sorry if it wasn't clear. functions (in my normal day) reside in /functions and get uploaded from there. but as you can see from the code above, the source directory has been taken by ./output/server and creates a single function in the dashboard, "server".  I need to do other work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nuxt 3 creates a single function ("server") and deploys to Cloud Functions. If you want to deploy functions from another source directory as well e.g. for Firestore triggers then you can pass an array to `functions` property in the `firebase.json` as shown below:

```
{
  "functions": [
    { "source": ".output/server", "codebase": "nuxt_app" },
    {
      "predeploy": "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build",
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "cloud_functions"
    }
  ]
}
```

Checkout the documentation to learn more about [Managing multiple source packages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#managing_multiple_source_packages_monorepo).

---

If you are not using background functions like Firestore or Cloud Storage triggers and just using HTTP callable functions, then you can use [NuxtJS Server Routes](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/server-routes) to deploy HTTP  endpoints.